# She is one of (the) better speakers. - need "the"?

Tags: articles, usage, definite-article

**Example 1**

> He was one of many American writers.

> He was one of the many American writers.

**Example 2**

> He was one of few famous American writers.

> He was one of the few famous American writers.

**Example 3**

> She is one of better speakers.

> She is one of the better speakers.

Which is the correct usage, with or without "the"?

Comment: "She is one of better speakers" is incorrect.  **The** is required.

Comment: "Better" isn't like "many" or "few". It doesn't express a quantity. Would you say "She is one of good speakers" or for that matter "one of best speakers"?

Answer (score 2):

Example 1 & 2. Both are correct, but the meaning changes subtly. Using "the" implies some subset of writers or American writers, but there isn't any real substantial change in meaning.

Example 3. "the" is definitely needed.